# How to insert they same field in other database

Tags: python, flask, couchdb

Lets say i have 2 databases.The column names of the two databases are as follows:

```
db1: name, age, gender, mother_name, father_name  
db2: name, gender, status, birthdate
```

As you can see, both db1 and db2 have common fields of 'name' and 'gender'. I want to insert the data from db2 in db1 which have they same fields.

Answer (score 1):

if you give us an expected output it could be more precise. But as i understand:

```
db1 = db1.merge(db2, on=["name","gender"], how="left")
```