# How to insert the value of common fields between two database

Tags: python, flask, couchdb

Lets say i have 2 databases.The column names of the two databases are as follows:

```
db1: name, age, gender, mother_name, father_name  
db2: name, gender, status, birthdate
```

As you can see, both database1 and database2 have common fields of 'name' and 'gender'. I want to insert the data from db2 in db1 which have they same fields.

Comment: Is there any reason for duplicating the name and gender in both dbs? You'd try to avoid duplication as much as possible.

Comment: what i mean is i want to get the value db2 which have they same field name in db1

Comment: Yes I know what you mean. What I am asking is why, and if there is a reason for duplicating the data across two difference databases

Comment: oh i see, sorry my bad. it just a task for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert they same field in other database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59445001/how-to-insert-they-same-field-in-other-database)